# Typescript without module loader?

Tags: typescript

I am stuck with an old software that uses aspx pages. 
I have some controls (ascx) that can work almost as a small Single Page Applications (for example a control that lets you register to a Newsletter,or a control that lets the user customize the news feed). (i know... its not really a SPA... )

I started using VUE.js for this small micro-projects. I managed to make it all work with plain JavaScript.

Now I wanted to use typescript instead of JavaScript.

The issue I have: when I create my typescripts and reference some modules like the VUE or my own, it always writes in the generated js file some "**require** " commands (transpiled to ES5) or some **Import** commands if transpiled to ES6.

As far as I read, these commands are supposed to be used by some module loaders on the server. But I don't have a Node.Js server nor a Javascript building infrastructure. Is there a way to tell typescript just to ignore those commands? I would then reference manually the needed JS-genereated  files with the modules inseide y ascx-control.

Comment: browserify?....

Answer (score 16):

In your `tsconfig.json` the `module` property should be `none`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "none"
    }
}
```

Now there are no more `amd` or `system` code. And now you can't use any more `import` and `export` statements.

Without this, TypeScript does not know the order of your scripts, and you can have Js undefined errors.

To fix this, just add a [triple slash directive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html) instead of `import` statement

Now TypeScript compile all the scripts in the right order.
Also use `outFile` instead of `out` because is deprecated.

Comment: In my use case I get `src/errors.ts:25:14 - error TS1148: Cannot use imports, exports, or module augmentations when '--module' is 'none'.

25 export class AttributeError extends Error {` when using `'module': 'none'`.  How do I fix that?

Comment: I mentioned above that you can't use import/export without module

Comment: @Jus my new answer above might help you

Comment: `"module": "none"` and `"outFile": "something.js"` doesn't produce any output. Any idea why?

Comment: do you have any other compilation errors? it might be configured not to output in case of error.

Answer (score 4):

Ofcourse you can. You just have to configure tsc to output the code without a the module loader statements.

For example, all the code into one big file.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "outFile": "www/js/bundle.js",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "sourceRoot": ""
    }
}
```

That might limit your use of the ES6 import statements. You might have to use the typescript defined **namespaces** instead.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that out

Comment: This does not work, because `out` (deprecated use `outFile` instead) does not respect any script order, and you can have a lot of errors in Js

Comment: error TS6131: Cannot compile modules using option 'outFile' unless the '--module' flag is 'amd' or 'system'

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar situation, old aspx system where I wanted to use ts -> js transpilation followed by system.web.optimization bundling.

My specific problem was related to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42234096/how-to-consume-the-moment-js-typescript-definition-file-if-my-site-is-already-us) i.e. using moment.js in a **typed way** while **avoiding output being generated like**

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
    value: !0
});
var moment = require("moment");
```

which would cause a js error like

```
ReferenceError: exports is not defined
```

I found that adding

```
"module" : none
```

to tsconfig.json along with a copy of the moment.d.ts file with their line

```
 export = moment;
```

removed or commented out.

```
 {
      "compileOnSave": true,
      "compilerOptions": {
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "outDir": "scriptoutput", //,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "module": "none"
        //"typeRoots": [ "node_modules/@types/", "node_modules/moment/" ]
      },
      "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "wwwroot",
        "scriptoutput"
      ],
      "include": [
        "script/custom-typings/moment.d.ts",
        "**/*"
      ]
    }
```

**worked a treat**, I now have my ts working fine, without any module loading, and with the typing that helps make typescript awesome !