# How can I get Vue.js 2.0 typings for TypeScript working with Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, typescript-typings

I'm trying to get Vue.js 2.0 typings working with TypeScript in Visual Studio. Previously, I had used [these typings](https://github.com/DAB0mB/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/vue/vue.d.ts) from DefinitelyTyped, but they are for Vue.js 1.0 and thus don't match up. However, they did work just fine and let me work with the `Vue` type.

I've since transitioned to using the typing files that come with Vue.js releases ([here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/tree/dev/types)). I have included them in my project in my `~/Scripts/typings/vue` folder, but my project does not understand them.

I've gathered that these typing files are meant to be used via import/export possibly? There are no other typing files I am using that work this way, so I am not sure how to correctly implement the typings such that they are available globally to my project.

I have a sample solution that shows an example of what I've tried - [download here from my github repo](https://github.com/BaseballTheater/BaseballTheater/files/825287/WebApplication1.zip).

Here's the structure of my `Scripts` folder:

[image]

**_references.d.ts** contents

```
/// <reference path="typings/vue/index.d.ts" />
```

**vue_test.ts** contents

```
namespace Test
{
    export class MyClass
    {
        public initialize()
        {
            var component = this.getComponent();
        }

        private getComponent(): Vue.Component
        {
            return Vue.component("test", {
                template: "<div></div>",
                props: ["test"],
                methods: {
                    onClick: () =>
                    {
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

What I would expect is that I would have access to the `Vue.Component` namespace and other namespaces that are declared in `typings/vue/index.d.ts`, but this does not seem to be the case.

I did attempt to import the exported class into `global`, like this:

```
import * as _Vue from "./index";

declare global
{
    export class Vue extends _Vue
    {

    }
}
```

However, this only allows me to access the root `Vue` class, and thus I cannot do things like specify `Vue.Component` as a type, or any other namespace beyond `Vue`.

**Other information:**
Visual Studio 2015
Vue.js version 2.2.1
TypeScript version 2.1

**UPDATE after suggestions from @unional**
Here is my new folder structure:
[image]

No more _references.d.ts, using tsconfig.json instead. The tsconfig.json file contains this:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "sourceMap": true
    },
    "include": [
        "../../**/*.ts"
    ]
}
```

The above imports all .ts files in the project. The `~/Scripts/typings/custom-typings/vue.d.ts` file contains the following:

```
export * from "vue"
export as namespace Vue
```

Visual Studio tells me `Cannot find module 'vue'`, so my typings are still not functional, although the tsconfig.json file works (I added the jQuery typing to verify that).

Here is a link to the updated solution showing the new problems: [[link]](https://github.com/BaseballTheater/BaseballTheater/files/836016/WebApplication1.zip)

Comment: My answer here is probably what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42234096/how-to-consume-the-moment-js-typescript-definition-file-if-my-site-is-already-us/42322335#42322335

Comment: @unional I can't seem to get your suggestion working. I don't have a tsconfig.json file. Maybe you could demo it with my sample solution I linked in my post?

Comment: Probably worth create one. Using `/// <reference` is very tedious in the long run. Just create it in the root of your project.

Comment: I see. Looked at your project and it is C# with some TS.

Haven't work on VS and C# for quite a while so I am not sure how VS configure things.
Maybe this would work? https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4161#issuecomment-128162692

Comment: Also here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#improved-support-for-tsconfigjson-in-visual-studio-2015

Comment: I've made some progress, but I'm still having some problems. I've updated the main post describing them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to use information from @unional's comment, but with a slight change:

I added this to my custom-vue.d.ts file:

```
import * as _Vue from 'vue';
export as namespace Vue;
export = _Vue;
```

Additionally, I had to create a `package.json` file with the following:

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "vue": "^2.2.1"
    }
}
```

Finally, I needed to add a `node_modules` folder at the same scope as my `tsconfig.json` file. It has the following:

```
+-- node_modules
|   +-- vue
|   |   +-- package.json
|   |   +-- types
|   |   |   +-- index.d.ts
|   |   |   +-- options.d.ts
|   |   |   +-- plugin.d.ts
|   |   |   +-- vnode.d.ts
|   |   |   +-- vue.d.ts
```

`package.json` simple contains:

```
{
  "typings": "types/index.d.ts"
}
```

And things are now WORKING

**Edit**
Alternatively, I discovered I could avoid the whole `node_modules` thing by setting `tsconfig.json`'s property for `moduleResolution` to `Classic`. After doing that, I changed my `custom-vue.d.ts` import to look like this:

```
import * as _Vue from "../vue/index";
```

Comment: Nice work. It occurred to me that you could use NPM locally and then add its output and installs to version control. That is close to what you have done manually. Also, to understand what is happening with `node_modules`, you can read the write-up on module resolution here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html

Comment: @ShaunLuttin Yes, that is interesting. I have actually re-modified things again to avoid the node_modules stuff by using `Classic` module resolution. I edited my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 10):

#### With NPM

Drop down to the command line in your app's root directory to use NPM and the TypeScript command line interface.

- If you do not already have a package.json file, then first run `npm init`.
- Then to install vue.js, run `npm install --save vue`.
- To install its types run `npm install --save-dev @types/vue`.
- If you also lack a tsconfig.json file, then run `tsc --init`.
- At that point, you will be able to build by running `tsc`.

#### Without NPM

Not using NPM is unconventional and will require a lot of manual work. Here is one of those manual approaches.

Download VueJS 2.1.1 [from the GitHub repo](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/releases). After extracting the archive,

1. Put the contents of `dist` into `Scripts/vuejs` directory,
2. Put the contents of `typings` into `typings/vuejs` directory,
3. Add a tsconfig.json file to your project's root that his this content.

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ....... other properties omitted      
    "typeRoots": [
      "./typings/"
    ],
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es2015", "dom", "es2015.promise" ]
  }
}
```

Then, at the top of the file that will be using Vue, add a relative import statement.

```
import * as Vue from "../typings/vuejs";

interface MyComponent extends Vue {
  message: string
  onClick (): void
}

export default {
    template: '<button @click="onClick">Click!</button>',
    data: function () {
        return {
            message: 'Hello!'
        }
    },
    methods: {
        onClick: function () {
            window.alert(this.message)
        }
    }
}
```

#### Example

Here is an updated version of your WebApplication1 example.

https://github.com/bigfont/StackOverflow/tree/master/TypeScriptVueJsTypes

#### See also:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html

https://github.com/vuejs/vue

Comment: We do not use npm in our projects, so this is unfortunately not a solution for me

Comment: @jake Wow. I'm so sorry.

Comment: @Jake You do actually use NPM: https://github.com/BaseballTheater/BaseballTheater/blob/master/package.json

Comment: Ah yes, sorry - I DO in the project you've linked, but not in all the projects for which I need to solve this problem. :(

Comment: What is the name of the project that have this problem? Is it only the `BaseballTheatre` project? @Jake

Comment: Unfortunately I can't share the project in question online, but the zip I linked in the main post contains the issue in the same way

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137849/discussion-between-shaun-luttin-and-jake).

Comment: New development! I have discovered a slight change to your original method from @unional's first comment that is working for me from here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3180. I have added it to my original post. It may be worth editing this post to reflect the same.

Comment: @Jake What does the slight change provide that the original method does not? I am trying to understand.

Comment: The original suggestion from unional did not include the `export = _Vue;` line, which is what made the difference

Comment: @Jake That much makes sense. What I am trying to learn, is what advantage the import and re-export as `_Vue` provides. The answer that I provided did not include that import and re-export; what advantage does including it bring? I haven't seen that pattern and am wondering, for your use case, why it was necessary to make things work for you. #learning

Comment: Turns out the final piece WAS a package.json file. I had to add `"vue": "^2.2.1"` to my dependencies and things began to work.

Comment: Also, as to the advantage of the export, I am unsure why exactly that works. That was due to the advice from @unional.

Comment: This answer is not correct. The "types" that are installed by npm are a "stub" and you get a warning:"@types/vue@2.0.0: This is a stub types definition for vuejs (https://github.com/vuejs/vue). vuejs provides its own type definitions, so you don't need @types/vue installed!"

Answer (score 1):

Since the error is at compile time, No big problem in it. you can use this plugin to for faster development from **[here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.VuejsPack)**

Also, the code should be as

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Component from 'vue-class-component'
// The @Component decorator indicates the class is a Vue component
@Component({

  template: ''
})
export default class MyComponent extends Vue {



}
```

and so on. You can still use the vuejs inside your cshtml files.