# Typescript does not resolve definition file for npm package

Tags: typescript, npm

I just published a npm [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nano-data-binding) written in typescript. Currently I have a lot of trouble getting the definition recognized by typescript (webback and vscode). The only solution that worked so far was to create a folder with the definition in `node_modules/@types`

Briefly this is my package setup:

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...
        "outDir": "./lib/",
        "declaration": true,
        "declarationDir": "./src/",
    }
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
    ...
    "types": "./index.d.ts",
}
```

**index.d.ts**

```
/// <reference path="src/nano-data-binding.d.ts" />
```

**src/nano-data-binding.d.ts**

I keep it in `/src` because it's autogenerated and I cannot control the path of the import. Also if I try to use only `declare var ...` without `import export` statements to get a script instead of a module.

```
import { StringOrHTMLElement } from './interfaces/nano-data-binding';
export declare function nanoBind(parent: HTMLElement, ...selectors: StringOrHTMLElement[]): HTMLElement[];
export declare function nanoBindAll(parent: HTMLElement, ...selectors: string[]): HTMLElement[];
```

Feel free to install the package, maybe it is just a small mistake somewhere. Basically I want to get the `nanoBind()` and `nanoBindAll()` declared as globals.

**Edit**

Additional things I tried. Nothing works.

**package.json** - Npm package

```
{
    ...
    "types": "lib/nano-data-binding.d.ts",
    "typings": "lib/nano-data-binding.d.ts",
    "typescript": {
        "definition": "lib/nano-data-binding.d.ts"
    },
}
```

**tsconfig.json** - Local project

```
{
    ...
    "files": [
        "node_modules/nano-data-binding/lib/nano-data-binding.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Have you distributed the typing files in your package? You also don't need the redirection (using index.d.ts and use /// <ref). Just point to the actual typing files from package.json directly.

Comment: BTW, `/// <reference` is for global script files, as a package, you would not use that syntax. Just `import '...'`.

Comment: I have tried all these suggestions before posting, I was pointing to the actual file. I also tried using `typings`. And various other things. It just refuses to register as a definition. The definition is definitely in the package.

Comment: I've been looking at other packages trying to figure out if I deed something wrong. Nothing stands out. Is there a way to confirm that an interface is loaded, other than just waiting for the error?

Comment: Can you show how the nano-data-binding.d.ts looks like? It should be automatic, you don't have to do anything except `types/typings: ...` in your package.json. See any of my packages for example. e.g. `color-map`

Comment: I looked at your package and the d.ts file is not in `lib`. It is in `src`

Comment: see https://github.com/visual-space/nano-data-binding/issues/2

Comment: @unional Thank you for taking the time to check it. It's unexpected to see that your IDE actuallly registers the definition. In my case I just got this message from Vscode  `Cannot find name 'nanoBind'`. Eventually I figured out the problem. Check the latest answer.

Answer (score 2):

In your `package.json` you need to rename the `types` field to `typings`
And yes, triple slash directive is not needed here

Comment: I used the triple slash in order to be able to add more definitions, indeed it's not really needed. Before posting I tried pointing directly to the folder and to the root `index.d.ts` where the actual definition was located.

Comment: "types" and "typings" are synonymous https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html

Answer (score 1):

Finally found something that works. It looks like it's enough to use `index.d.ts` in the root level or specify a custom route in `package.json` of the package.

The problem was with my definition. It needs to declare a module.

**index.d.ts**

```
type StringOrHTMLElement = string | HTMLElement
declare var nanoBind: (parent: HTMLElement, ...selectors: StringOrHTMLElement[]) => HTMLElement[];
declare var nanoBindAll: (parent: HTMLElement, ...selectors: string[]) => HTMLElement[];

declare module 'nano-data-binding' {
    export var nanoBind: (parent: HTMLElement, ...selectors: any[]) => HTMLElement[];
    export var nanoBindAll: (parent: HTMLElement, ...selectors: string[]) => HTMLElement[];
}
```

And than the way it is imported

**main.ts**

```
import * as ndb from 'nano-data-binding' // Imports script and definition
require('nano-data-binding') // Ignores definition
```

Comment: This is not the way. So I know what’s your problem. Will post an answer

Comment: This is a way of augmenting someone elses type defs.. I've posted an answer above.. types -> typings in package.json

Comment: I found [globals.d.ts](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/global-d-ts.html) in the typescript documentation. Maybe I got it the wrong way. Says that `namespace` is for globals, which is my case.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is due to your tsconfig.json tries to explicitly include the typing file.
npm package typings file are loaded automatically when you specify either `types` or `typings` field in your package.json.

When you remove the entry in your `files` array in your tsconfig.json, it should just work.

The solution you found (adding `declare module 'nano-data-binding' { }`) is a solution for creating custom typings for some packages without typings.

To be a bit more technical, when a typings file (d.ts) does not contain top-level import export statement, it is an ambient script file and it is globally scoped. That's why you need `declare module '...'` to indicate which module your are adding typings for.

You typically use them as in [How to consume the Moment.js TypeScript definition file if my site is already using moment.min.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42234096/how-to-consume-the-moment-js-typescript-definition-file-if-my-site-is-already-us/42322335#42322335)

Comment: The trouble is that I have removed the `files` option from `tsconfig.json` some time ago. A lot of the tests I made were running without this option. I will keep looking into it. I hope I will find the real trouble maker. Maybe I should try to import it in a clean project. Maybe something interferes. I will be doing some tests and report back on the results.Thank you for the answer!