# Use Typescript to output plain JS, not a module?

Tags: javascript, typescript

For example ...

**index.ts**

```
import { x } from "./other-funcs";

function y() {
    alert("test");
}

x(y);
```

**other-funcs.ts**

```
import { z } from "some-module";

export function x(callback: () => void): void {
    z();
    callback();
}
```

(Note that "other-funcs.ts" uses an import statement to import a function from some other module.)

I'd like to compile `index.ts` and have it result in a JS file which can be directly included in an HTML file, e.g. `<script src="index.js"></script>`, and have it immediately execute in the browser (show the alert).

**sample output**

```
function x(callback) {
    callback();
}

function y() {
    alert("test");
}

x(y);
```

I can't seem to get the proper TS config to get this outcome. Please advise.

Note: This is not the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40084498) because I need to use `import`, etc. I just want the result to be simple JS output without a module loader.

Comment: You can't use `import` to do that. However, you can use a `namespace`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript without module loader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40084498/typescript-without-module-loader)

Answer (score 7):

## Vanilla JavaScript

Whenever you use `import` it will always build out to a module. You can however use `namespaces` alongside `"module": "system"`, this can then be output to a single file (or multiple files).

so, for a very basic project you would have the following:

### tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "system",
    "outFile": "./lib.js"
  },
  "include": [
    "./**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

Next you would then create your files to look like this:

### index.ts

```
namespace MyNamespace {
  // This is a private method that cannot be accessed in other files
  // the reason for that is because it isn't exported.
  function y() {
    alert("test");
  }

  x(y)
}
```

### functions.ts

```
namespace MyNamespace {
  // This method can be referenced in other files because it is exported.
  export function x(callback: () => void): void {
    callback();
  }
}
```

### The generated browser code

```js
var MyNamespace;
(function(MyNamespace) {
  function x(callback) {
    callback();
  }
  MyNamespace.x = x;
})(MyNamespace || (MyNamespace = {}));
var MyNamespace;
(function(MyNamespace) {
  function y() {
    alert("test");
  }
  MyNamespace.x(y);
})(MyNamespace || (MyNamespace = {}));
```

You can then use these methods/functions outside of the namespace by simply by calling them via the namespace:

```
MyNamespace.y()
MyNamespace.x(MyNamespace.y)
// etc.
```

---

## Using requirejs

To use `import` within your project, you will need a 3rd party library [requirejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/requirejs). This will allow you to use modules within the browser.

So, to do this, we first need to have the proper config file which looks similar to above the only difference is `"module": "amd"`.

### tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "amd",
    "outFile": "./lib.js"
  },
  "include": [
    "./**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

Next we need to create the proper typescript main file:

### index.ts

```
requirejs(['functions'], function (util: any) {
  function y() {
    alert("test");
  }

  util.x(y)
})
```

Since this is using a 3rd party library, it is initialized differently (using `requirejs()`). This tells requirejs that this is the entry point to the application thus this is only needed once.

### functions.ts

```
export function x(callback: () => void): void {
  callback();
}
```

### The generated browser code

```js
define("functions", ["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    function x(callback) {
        callback();
    }
    exports.x = x;
});
requirejs(['functions'], function (util) {
    function y() {
        alert("test");
    }
    util.x(y);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.6/require.js"></script>
```

If your script is in an external file, you can use `data-main` on the script tag, requirejs will then load the file automatically.

```
<script data-main="./lib" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.6/require.js"></script>
```

---

## Experimental Modules

[This feature is still experimental, and not supported in all browsers](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/08/es6-in-depth-modules/). All you need to do is use the `type="module"` attribute on your script tag:

```
<script type="module" src="./path/to/main.js"></script>
```

### tsconfig.json

**Note:** that here we use both a different `target` and `module`, and also an `outDir`.
**Note:** `es2016` is not a valid module type.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "es2015",
    "outDir": "./lib"
  },
  "include": [
    "./**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

### index.ts

**Note:** `import` uses a `.js` extension otherwise the browser can't load it unless you have rewrite rules in place.

```
import { x } from './functions.js'
function y() {
  alert("test");
}

x(y)
```

### functions.ts

```
export function x(callback: () => void): void {
  callback();
}
```

This will output nearly the same as the ts files (Stackoverflow doesn't support external js files unless they are hosted somewhere, so no snippet here):

```
// index.js
import { x } from './functions.js';
function y() {
    alert("test");
}
x(y);

// functions.js
export function x(callback) {
    callback();
}
```

Comment: I will update the OP but I do need to use `import` within "other-funcs" for instance. Which I don't think is valid within a namespace -- right?

Comment: To use import you then need to also use requirejs

Comment: @JoshM. I have updated the answer with a way to use `import` within your browser application.

Comment: @JoshM. The answer now has 3 options for you to choose from to write a working browser application with typescript with/without `imports`.

Comment: Thanks for your dedication! I've decided to use rollup in order to make my generated JS code easily runnable in the browser.