# TypeScript - Compiling to single files

Tags: typescript

I am currently writing a project that has some very long source files, which is great for imports but not so great for maintenance; for example:

**/main/core.ts**

```
export type Foo { ... }

export interface Bar { ... }

export class Baz { ... }
```

**/main/data.ts**

```
import { Foo, Bar } from "core";

const x: Foo = ...;
export class BarImpl implements Bar { ... }
```

Currently these files compile to:

- /dist/core.js
- /dist/core.d.ts
- /dist/core.ts.map
- /dist/data.js
- /dist/data.d.ts
- /dist/data.ts.map

As mentioned, it's a bit of a maintenance nightmare, with source files getting longer and longer as more features are added. What I'd like to do is split these out into their own source files under a new directory; for example:

**/main/core/foo.ts**

```
export type Foo { ... }
```

**/main/core/bar.ts**

```
export interface Bar { ... }
```

**/main/core/baz.ts**

```
export class Baz { ... }
```

I can do this, but it has a knock on effect with imports; for example:

**/main/data/barimpl.ts**

```
import { Foo } from "core/foo";
import { Bar } from "core/bar";

const x: Foo = ...
export class BarImpl implements Bar { ... }
```

Is it possible to:

1. Split **/main/core.ts** into **/main/core/foo.ts** etc. and still compile them to **/dist/core.js** etc.?
2. Maintain imports like `import { Foo, Bar } from "core"` rather than having to split imports by file?

Comment: I am new to typescript myself, but you might want to look into using namespaces. See [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html) or a [relevant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55269780/375093)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a barrel to your codebase.

```
// main/core/index.ts
export * from './foo';
export * from './bar';
export * from './baz';
```

```
// Example consumer
import { Foo, Bar, Baz } from 'core';
```